# How to get chrome console like quick suggestions for objects properties in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In chrome Devtool selecting an element will give corresponding properties and method applicable on that via a dot(.). But in vscode it gives gibberish. How to get those suggestions of chrome devtool in vscode.
[image: I want this]

[image: I get this]

Comment: What do you mean "gibberish"? Your first example has HTML, the second JavaScript. You're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: In both case I'm trying to get formEl.elements.post2   
In chrome devtool I get suggestions for 'post2'
But in vscode there is none

Comment: @Sourav9063 what is the file extension? How is `formEl` declared?

Comment: app.js            .       const formEl = document.querySelector('.form');

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, here is why:

Chrome DevTools console executes code in the context of the page as you type so for example it executes `Object.keys(formEl.elements)` and with the results it can show you that `formEl.elements` has a post and userName property.

Visual Studio Code only shows you what it can statically analyse, and in this case it analyses that formEl is of type `Element` and not `HTMLFormElement` cause it doesn't know that `document.querySelector('.form')` returns a form element so the only autocomplete suggestions are other symbols used through your code.

One way to to get autocomplete is to use TypeScript and define yourself what type is formEl.

Comment: This answer is good except for the "it's not possible" part: it is definitely possible for a VS Code extension which includes a TS language server (TLS) plugin to execute the program on every change and inform the TLS of the newly-discovered type information. However, this is a very challenging task, and AFAIK no plugin like this exists yet.

Comment: @jsejcksn Even if you write a VS Code extension that runs the program on every code change it will need to execute the code in the scope and it's possible that the code path is not executed instantly when the program is ran, this means you need to perform actions in your program to hit the code path.

Comment: That's right: additional contextual state related to the editor would be needed as well.

Comment: i heard jetbrains webstorm can do this

Comment: @Sourav9063 Just played a bit with WebStorm, it seems it does some guesses that `formEl.elements` is of of type `HTMLFormControlsCollection` but it can't actually tell that it has a post and userName property.